# synchronous SSRS report execution

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I need to execute an SSRS report on demand, not time-triggered, and wait for the completion result.

I'm using:

```
EXEC ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription', @EventData=@suscription_id
```

But it is asynchronous execution. Is there a parameter I can set to wait for finalization?

I'm also trying this work arround, can it be improved?

```
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @status VARCHAR(255) = 'Pending'

    EXEC ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent @EventType = 'TimedSubscription'
        ,@EventData = @suscription_id

    WHILE @status = 'Pending'
    BEGIN
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

        SELECT @status = LastStatus
        FROM reportserver.dbo.subscriptions
        WHERE subscriptionid = @suscription_id
    END
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

Comment: Any solutions I've used in the past have had to pool the table. I haven't checked in years if synchronous functionality has been added, but I suspect not as I haven't heard anything about it on the "grape vine".