# SSRS comprehensive list of possible values for LastStatus

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

There are Reports and subscriptions to those reports in SSRS. Related Question: [synchronous SSRS report execution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68470289/15044787)

I created a stored procedure to force them to execute on-demand and not on a scheduled basis.

I need this stored procedure to continue only after the report was successfully generated or failed or after a determined timeout I will be established.

As this is an asynchronous matter, I have to wait and pool the last status for each particular subscription on a timely basis.

I found that after I trigger the Subscription on-demand, there is a lag before the current status turns into "Pending". I wonder if there will be any case that when pooling for the status the answers could be any different than "Pending".

Also, I found that there is no clear flag for success or failure. I wanted to know if there is a chance that I get status after "pending" that indicates another state that is not the final success or failure.

This algorithm will fail if any of those supposed states exists, that is why I'm asking. I couldn't find a comprehensive list of possible states for a subscription

```
DECLARE @status VARCHAR(255) = 'Pending'

    EXEC ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent @EventType = 'TimedSubscription'
        ,@EventData = @suscription_id
WHILE @start > dateadd(MINUTE, - @timeout, getdate())
        AND @status = 'Pending'
    BEGIN
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05' -- wait before pooling status again                      
    
        SELECT @status = LastStatus
        FROM reportserver.dbo.subscriptions
        WHERE subscriptionid = @suscription_id
            AND LastRunTime > @start
    END
```

Comment: Its totally not clear what your question is... please clarify.

Comment: @DaleK look at it now, thanks

Comment: You can always check the execution log to check the status.